# ¿Como aceptar un alerta popup de Javascript con Puppeter?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer, saml

Tengo un script que usa puppeter para iniciar sesión automáticamente, utilizando para ello SAML. Cuando ejecuto el script se abre la ventana de chromium y se dirige a la pagina sin problemas, pero cuando aparece el popup que solicita identificar al usuario solo puedo seleccionar el certificado de forma manual.

[image: Petición de certificado]

Intente simular el apretar el Enter

```
await page.bringToFront();
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
```

y reconocer este popup como un Dialog

```
await page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
console.log(dialog.message());
await dialog.accept();
});
```

Pero ninguno de los 2 funciono.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo con puppeter?

Muchas gracias.